# AS3 Alchemy and ByteArray.setPixels() issue. "bytearray.position = 0" doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, alchemy

I'm encoding the BitmapData using this method:
http://www.websector.de/blog/2009/06/21/speed-up-jpeg-encoding-using-alchemy/

Code example:

```
var loader:CLibInit = new CLibInit;
as3_jpeg_wrapper = loader.init();
var baSource: ByteArray = bitmapData.clone().getPixels( new Rectangle( 0, 0, WIDTH,   HEIGHT) );                                
var baAlchmey: ByteArray = as3_jpeg_wrapper.write_jpeg_file(baSource, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3, 2, quality);
```

After encoding i need to convert resulting byteArray back to BitmapData. I'm using `setPixels()` method. 
For example:

```
baAlchemy.position = 0;
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height);
bd.setPixels(rect, baAlchemy);
```

And i get "Error #2030: End of file was encountered?".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the bytes of a compressed JPEG  to [`setPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixels%28%29).

However, according to the documentation `setPixels()`, it the second argument to be:

> A ByteArray object that consists of 32-bit unmultiplied pixel values to be used in the rectangular region

Or, in other words, an uncompressed image. You will first have to [decompress](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1089) your image, before you can render it into a `BitmapData`